# Ajax run duplicate when I put window.location.hash, why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, hash

My ajax had no problem, I had test them. Only when I place the          window.location.hash = 0;, then the ajax run duplicate at the first time, if I remove           window.location.hash = 0;, everything is OK. What did I do wrong.

```js
$('#post_show_per_page').change(function(){
   window.location.hash = 0;

 load_Ajax_content();
});
function load_Ajax_content(){

  //ajax code here.
  }
```

Comment: Do you have any events binded to window onhashchange? Also, does post_show_per_page change when the window hash changes?

Comment: Oh, yes, Thanks you very much. I got it. Do you any way to prevent them to run duplicate. I had a code if(window.location.hash) {
load_Ajax_content();
} I was thinking can I remove window.lcoation.hash instead of set it 0

Comment: That'd still count as a hash change. Why don't you rely on the `hashchange` handler to call `load_Ajax_content` rather than calling it as above?

Comment: Because I need hashchange to get the hash value to run other ajax code. Right now, I think I need to find a way to remove window.location.hash = 0;
because I don't need it, so I set it is 0.